# Generate javascript client from Servicestack api metadata/swagger

Tags: servicestack, swagger-codegen

is there any way to auto-generate ServiceStack javascript (no typescript) client based on metadata/Swagger? It would be good to integrate that somehow with webpack.

I am not sure is it possible to do this with swagger-js-codegen (*This package generates a nodejs or angularjs class from a swagger specification file*).

Actually swagger plugin doesn't share service to access swagger.json to get complete schema (the schema is splited). Is there any workaround to use swagger codegen for javascript?

By accessing http://localhost:12116/resources you can get

```
{"swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/resource/assignroles"},{"path":"/resource/auth"},{"path":"/resource/authenticate"},{"path":"/resource/criteria"},{"path":"/resource/import"},{"path":"/resource/tenders"},{"path":"/resource/unassignroles"}],"apiVersion":"1.0","basePath":"http://localhost:12116","info":{"title":"App"}}
```

and using http://localhost:12116/resource/import

```
{"swaggerVersion":"1.2","apiVersion":"1.0","basePath":"http://localhost:12116","resourcePath":"/import","apis":[{"path":"/import/stats","operations":[{"method":"GET","nickname":"BrowseImportStats","parameters":[],"errorResponses":[]}]},{"path":"/import/tenders/changes/apply","operations":[{"method":"GET","nickname":"ApplyChanges","parameters":[],"errorResponses":[]},{"method":"POST","nickname":"ApplyChanges","parameters":[{"paramType":"body","name":"body","required":false,"allowMultiple":false,"type":"ApplyChanges"}],"errorResponses":[]},{"method":"PUT","nickname":"ApplyChanges","parameters":[{"paramType":"body","name":"body","required":false,"allowMultiple":false,"type":"ApplyChanges"}],"errorResponses":[]},{"method":"DELETE","nickname":"ApplyChanges","parameters":[],"errorResponses":[]}]},{"path":"/import/tenders/sync","description":"summary","operations":[{"method":"GET","summary":"summary","nickname":"ImportTenders","parameters":[],"errorResponses":[]}]}],"models":{"ImportTenders":{"id":"ImportTenders","properties":{}},"ApplyChanges":{"id":"ApplyChanges","properties":{}},"BrowseImportStats":{"id":"BrowseImportStats","description":"BrowseImportStats","properties":{}}}}
```

*update 2016-11-26*
I was able to generate documentation

```
C:\git\testapp>java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate -i http
://localhost:12116/resources -l javascript -o ./node_modules/testapp_api --additi
onal-properties emitJSDoc=false,usePromises=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've the OpenAPI/Swagger spec, you can leverage Swagger Codegen to generate not only JS API clients but API clients in other langauges (C#, Ruby, PHP, Python, etc), server stubs (Spring, NodeJS, etc) and API documentation.

Here is a good starting point: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#getting-started

(If you do not want to install anything, you can also generate code online: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators)

Comment: can you check my update about used Servicestack plugin? It generates splited schema and I am not sure is this supported by Swagger Codegen.

Comment: Yes, the latest master of Swagger Codegen has better support for splitted schema (FYI. Swagger Codegen leverages Swagger Parser to parse swagger files)

Comment: thnx for info. I have now problems with using that API in webpack. I had error when importing module ERROR in ./~/testapp_api/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ApiClient' in 'C:\git\testapp\n
ode_modules\testapp_api\src'
 @ ./~/testapp_api/src/index.js 28:4-705

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new and the team will help into it.